# Why Rust's raw pointer can access function and some parts of fields' information of a struct variable out of scope?

Tags: rust, struct, unsafe, raw-pointer

I want to use Rust raw pointer like `*const` to reproduce the security problem of use after free, but when I use the raw pointer to access fields or call the function of a freed struct variable, there's no panic occurred.

Here's my codes:

`new` method is used to create the struct more conveniently. `as_ptr` method is used to return the raw pointer of the struct itself.

```
pub struct Foo{
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Foo{
    pub fn new(data: &[u8]) -> Foo{
        Foo{ data: data.to_vec() }
    }
    pub fn as_ptr(&self) -> *const Foo{
        // return a raw pointer of this struct
        self as *const Foo    
    }
    pub fn test(&self){
        println!("test");
    }
}
```

`test` method above and `use_raw_ptr` method below are intended to reproduce the use after free problem.

```
pub unsafe fn use_raw_ptr(ptr: *const Foo){
    println!("{:?}", (*ptr).data);
}
```

When testing, I create a `Foo` struct variable `foo` in `match` blocks, which I suppose should be the scope of the `foo` variable. Then the raw pointer of `foo` is passed to `p` if `data` is legal. After `match` block, I try to use `p` to call the function `test` of `Foo` and access `data` field of `foo`, where I suppose use after free problem should appear because `foo` should be freed already.

```
fn main(){
    let data: Option<&[u8]> = Some(b"abc");
    let p = match data{
        Some(data) => {
            let foo = Foo::new(data);
            foo.as_ptr();
        } 
        None => std::ptr::null(),
    };
    unsafe {(*p).test()};
    println!("{:?}", data);
    unsafe{ use_raw_ptr(p) };
}
```

However, no panic occurrs when executing the codes and here's the output:

```
test
Some([97, 98, 99])
[192, 230, 41]
```

It also should be mentioned that the result of `use_raw_ptr` differs everytime I run the codes, but the length of printed result always match the input data. I wonder if this is because when `foo` is freed, some information like the length of `data` is still remained?

```
fn main(){
    let data: Option<&[u8]> = Some(b"abcde");
    // ... same as above
}

// output
test
Some([97, 98, 99, 100, 101])
[192, 230, 5, 252, 49]
```

Besides, I think that the reason of the succecc call of `unsafe{(*p).test()}` is that it calls the function of `Foo` struct instead of `foo` variable. I don't know if this is corrent and I'm wondering if I can make program panic here using raw pointer to access freed memory.

Comment: use unsafe => why I can do this ? => surprise pikachu face

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dereferencing a dangling pointer is undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour is, well ***undefined*** meaning that you cannot expect any behaviour, exepecting it to panic is therefore not valid.

Or in other words, **any** behaviour including but not limited to not changing the memory and therefore the values still being in the same memory locations, panicing, setting the pc on fire, [executing a game of Doom™](https://predr.ag/blog/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-undefined-behavior/) is possible.